# Swift UITableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath in multipleSection and multiple prototype cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a question about UITableView. I want to build a table with the first row is static cell where I use UIWebView to play video. The other rows below will be a list of videos. When I click on the video in the list, I want to play it at the first row.

Can anyone help me to set up the function didSelectRowAtIndexPath for this situation? Thank you very much.

Here is my code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        let cell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("staticCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! staticCell
        let htmlString = "<video width='100%' webkit-playsinline controls autoplay ><source src= 'http://203.162.121.235:1935/live/tranhieuapt.rqv3-1d9w-hx44-5y3m/playlist.m3u8'></video>"
        cell2.videoView.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: nil)
        return cell2
    } else if indexPath.section == 1 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("dynamicCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! dynamicCell
        // Get data function
        func getDataFromUrl(url:NSURL, completion: ((data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError? ) -> Void)) {
            NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data, response, error) in
                completion(data: data, response: response, error: error)
                }.resume()
        }
        // Download Image Function
        func downloadImage(url: NSURL){
            getDataFromUrl(url) { (data, response, error)  in
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
                    guard let data = data where error == nil else { return }
                    cell.thumnail.image = UIImage(data:data)
                }
            }
        }
        let vid = videoArray[indexPath.row]

        cell.titleLb.text = vid.vidTitle
        cell.viewLb.text  = vid.vidView
        cell.dateLb.text  = vid.vidDate


        let encodedUrl = vid.vidThumb.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())
        if let checkedUrl = NSURL(string: encodedUrl!) {
            cell.thumnail.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
            downloadImage(checkedUrl)
        }

        return cell
    }
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    return cell
}
```

Comment: If your question mentions Swift in the title and all the code in the question is written in Swift, and you're looking for an answer written in Swift, you **really** shouldn't tag your question `objective-c`.

Answer (score 0):

I think need to restructure your architecture.

You need to have a static `view` at the top (that has the player) and a `tableView` below it and on `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` just update the player.

Comment: Thank you for answer for my question. But I want to scroll my view. If I set a static view at the top, the frame' height of table view will be too short.

Comment: Do you want to have a vertical or horizontal scrolling on the `playerView`?

Comment: At the first, I design the screen with 2 objects: UIWebview for playing video, UITableView for showing list of videos. Then I see the height of Table View is too short, I just see 2 videos in the list and very hard to use the UIRefreshControl. So I want to add all of objects into a Table View then I can scroll whole screen (just like in web, I don't want to fix position of the video player) Can you give me an idea? Sorry about my bad English :(

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create custom view for tableView header:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let headerView = YourWebView()

    return headerView
}
```

Thus you`ll be able to scroll everything